# How nested loops are executed in this case?

Tags: javascript

Why the result is [[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]  ?

How is this code executed? Cause is not so intuitive..

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      row.push(0);
    }
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}
let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

Comment: you should move `let row = [];` between the two for loops - because every row will be the same array in your code

Comment: alternatively, `return Array.from({length:m}).map(() => Array(n).fill(0))`

Answer (score 0):

Your code adds to `row` m * n times. The `row` is pushed m times into new Array

The fact that you add to `row` after you push it into `newArray`, doesn't mean `row` is magically cleared

To prove it is the same array in each row, consider this code

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      row.push(0);
    }
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}
let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
matrix[0][0]=1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix));
```

See how changing `[0][0]` also changes `[1][0]` and `[2][0]` - that's because each row is the exact same array

*Note: In the solutions below, I've added `matrix[0][0] = 1` to demonstrate that the above problem is not present, i.e. each row is a different array - obviously you'd not include that line in your actual code*

Two simple solutions: 1 - set `row = []` after you push it

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      row.push(0);
    }
    newArray.push(row);
    row = [];
  }
  return newArray;
}
let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
matrix[0][0]=1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix));
```

solution 2: declare row inside the first loop

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  let newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    let row = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      row.push(0);
    }
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}
let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
matrix[0][0]=1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix));
```

and a modern solution

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  return Array.from({length: m}).map(() => Array(n).fill(0));
}
let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
matrix[0][0]=1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix));
```